# Where are the AGP 8.1.1 release notes?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

The release notes provided by the official [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin) page only have up to version 8.1 and lower AGP versions such as 8.0.x which can be read at the following [link](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-0-0-release-notes).

In the latest version of Android Studio through the APG Upgrade Assistans I can upgrade to AGP version 8.1.1.

I would like to know what happened to the release notes for this version.

Comment: This is typical Android or Google documentation. They aren't really into updating release notes, docs, etc.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be the best place for Android Studio and associated Gradle Plugin release notes https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/

Specifically, I believe 8.1.1 is named Giraffe Patch 1 and is here https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2023/08/android-studio-giraffe-patch-1-now.html